# What command can I use for deploying SSAS Tabular Model?

Tags: ssas

I would like to deploy a tabular model to SSAS server using Powershell.  What command can I use for deploying a tabular model?

Comment: This might help https://harbisingh.wordpress.com/2015/11/27/deploy-ssas-using-powershell/

Comment: @FaisalMehboob Thank you, the article is very useful.

Comment: @Summer You might want to write the solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as the correct answer. It makes it easier for others to find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my commands for deploying SSAS Tabular Model using Powershell.

```
# Generate Input Files for Tabular Model Deployment

# DEPLOYMENT WIZARD
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard#running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard-at-the-command-prompt

# navigate to directory of DeploymentWizard executable
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\"

# Run Deployment Wizard in "Answer Mode" to update input files (if needed)
.\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe `
    "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\My Project\My SubFolder\My Tabular Model\bin\Model.asdatabase" /a 

# Deploy Tabular Model to SSAS Server

# navigate to directory of DeploymentWizard executable
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\"

# Run Deployment Wizard in "Silent Mode" redirecting relevant 
# profiler events generated during deployment to an output file
.\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe `
    "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\My Project\My SubFolder\My Tabular Model\bin\Model.asdatabase" `
    /s:"C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\My Project\My SubFolder\My Tabular Model\bin\deployment_output.txt"
```